# LWC unit testing, Dynamic row level actions tests

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, js, lwc-jest

I implemented dynamic row level action as mentioned in documentation

```
getRowActions (row, doneCallback) {
        const actions = [];
            if (row['status'] == 'Active') {
                actions.push({
                    'label': 'Export',
                    'name': 'export'
                },
                {
                    'label': 'Delete',
                    'name': 'delete'
                }
                );

            } else {
                actions.push({
                    'label': 'Export',
                    'name': 'export'
                });
                
                }
                setTimeout(() => {
                    doneCallback(actions);
                });
    }
```

getRowActions being called perfectly fine from UI.

However, does not get called when I run it from Jest context.(Dispatching event)
Any suggestion on how to test this functionality?

more code:
HTML:

```
 <div class=data-table style="height: 500px;">
        <lightning-datatable
                key-field="id"
                data={data}
                columns={columns}
                onrowaction={handleRowAction}>
        </lightning-datatable>
 </div>
```

handleRowAction

```
 handleRowAction(event){
        const requestId = event.detail.row.legalHoldId
        if(event.detail.action.name==='delete'){
            code
        }
        else if(event.detail.action.name==='export') {
            code
        }
    }
```

Event dispatched successfully on jest.

Answer (score 0):

In the jest test case, we can trigger the dynamic getRowActions() function like this:

`componentElement.columns[0].typeAttributes.rowActions(mockData, loadActionDoneCallback);`

- where componentElement would be the mock document element
- try to access the typeAttributes of that column index where you have added it
- loadActionDoneCallback would be a mock jest function which you can create like this : `const loadActionDoneCallback = jest.fn();`
- mockData would be the data that